# Как написать тестовый сценарий(тест-кейс) для скрипта переноса новостей, с чего начать?

Tags: тестирование

Программисты разработали скрипт, переносящий новости со
старого сайта на новый. Теперь необходимо проверить правильно ли перенеслись новости. Каждая новость содержит: заголовок, подзаголовок, текст,
обязательную картинку-миниатюру, опциональное видео, опциональную галерею
картинок. Каждая новость относится к одному из 5 разделов.

Comment: То, что Вы описали слабо относится к тестированию. Это скорее проверка уже выполненной работы.

Comment: С чего вдруг? Обычная задача для куашки о проверке миграции данных.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала - вы проверяете перенос данных из одной БД в другую. Поэтому нужен доступ к обеим.
Далее кейсы:

1. Кол-во постов в новой БД = кол-ву в старой.
2. Проверка данных поста (наименование, описание, раздел и проч.). Тут есть варианты: можно сделать выборочно, можно сделать полностью, но не руками конечно же - придется писать тест который будет забирать данные по очереди и сравнивать.